# Oracle Apex PLSQL procedure to match pattern in column

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a table with following values:

[image]

In oracle Apex I have a form that takes name as manual text field. For each Name a specific format is given.
Ex: For seq 1, name should start with A , for 2 it should start with B. It can be any format for each name.

When i click on update button a procedure should be called that'd validate if the name matches its corresponding regex format in the NameFormat column.

I need help with the logic that can be written to use the regex pattern for each name and return successful or failed match accordingly.

Comment: What have you tried?  That seems like a relatively straightforward call to `regexp_like` but I'm not sure if you're having problems calling `regexp_like` or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, there's a table in your schema (let's call it `name_format`) which contains two columns (`seq` and `format`); its contents is as screenshot shows.

Based on that, I created a form page which contains several items:

- `P25_SEQ` is a select list item whose query is

  ```
  select seq||': '|| format d,
         seq r
  from name_format
  order by seq;
  ```
- `P25_NAME` is a text field which has **validation** (function body that returns error text) that checks whether value entered into that field follows format set by the `P25_SEQ` item:

  ```
  declare
    l_format name_format.format%type;
  begin
    select format
      into l_format
      from name_Format
      where seq = :P25_SEQ;

    if not regexp_like(:P25_NAME, l_format) then
       return 'Name does not follow format';
    end if;
  end;
  ```

When page is submitted, validation *fires* and returns error (left) or not (right). For example:

[image]